# How to use image id as source in jQuery attr('src',value)?

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem in a Jquery code. Please help me to fix this problem.

HTML Code for showing images:

```
<body>
    <div class="info_image">image1</div>
    <div class="info_image">image2</div>
    <div class="info_image">image3</div>
```

The image links with id:

```
    <div class="reference">
            <p><img id="image1" src="brush-seller.jpg"/></p>
            <p><img id="image2" src="Pest-seller.jpg"/></p>
            <p><img id="image3" src="pick-seller.jpg"/></p>
</body>
```

Now the problem is with JavaScript. I have to use **.attr('src',value)** tag to use the image id as source and show that image in first 3 div. So far I found a code which didn't work:

```
.attr('src','image/'+info_elem.find('.info_image').html())
```

Please help me to fix this jquery code.

Comment: you want put this images in div tags?

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: You want to display the image with id="image1" in the div with containing the text image1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` to iterate over the Div's . Fetch the html

And use `.css()` to set the corresponding background image

```
$('.info_image').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);  
    var imgId = $this.html(); // Assuming the div html contains just the image ID
    var imgSrc = $('#' + imgId).attr('src');

    $this.css('backgroundImage','url('+ imgSrc + ')');
})
```

Better to use HTML5 data attribute to store the image ID instead of the html as you might need to handle the cases of empty spaces or other characters...

```
<div class="info_image" data-image="image1">Here comes image1</div>
<div class="info_image" data-image="image2">Here comes image2</div>
<div class="info_image" data-image="image3">Here comes image3</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $('.info_image').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);  
            var imgId = $this.data('image'); 
            var imgSrc = $('#' + imgId).attr('src');

            $this.css('backgroundImage','url('+ imgSrc + ')');
        })
```

This will be lot cleaner